# A list<> of integer arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, list

I need a dynamic list of integer arrays.

I would think that it could be declared as:

```
list<int[10]> myListOfArrays;
```

But this doesn't work, and the compiler returns the errors:

```
error: 'std::_list_node<_Tp>::_M_data' has incomplete type
error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
```

Is there a way to do this?

The size of the integer arrays need not be dynamic, only the number of lists.

Comment: you can create vector of vector<int> or make it dynamic arrays.

Comment: Are you really sure you need a `list` and not a `vector`?

Comment: For this size of container I would opt for a `vector` like juanchopanza suggests

Answer (score 9):

Use a `std::list` of [`std::array<int,10>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 0):

`list<int*> myListOfArrays;` will work, particularly as you are happy with the arrays of ints having a static size.

Something like:

```
std::list<int*> listOfArrays;

int[10] intArray;

listOfArrays.push_back(intArray);
```

What you are really doing is storing int pointers in your list.

Comment: And what happens when the array goes out of scope, but not the `std::list<int *>`?  Embedding the arrays in the `std::list` (as with [`std::array<int,10>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)) results in better safety, better style, better maintainability, et cetera.

Comment: Furthermore, you can't know from a pointer whether it points asingle element or the first element of an array. If it is the latter, you have no idea how long the array is. So it is really quite fragile.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy Very true, but I'm keeping it simple. I don't think it's critical code he/she is working on or they probably wouldn't have asked this question in the first place. He/she even said that a static int array is fine for their purpose, the exact length is known.

Comment: In what way is your solution simpler than `std::list<std::array<int,10>>`?

Comment: As far as I can see the std::array<int, n> is still only "one dimensional"? Or am I missing something? 

Basicly what I need is a two dimensional array that has a dynamic size along one axis...

Comment: Nevermind, I missread the answer. An std::list of arrays, I think that could work :) 
I'll try it out...